# Can you geocode_by two different locations in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

So my model has two locations - a 'from' and a 'to' location. How can i geocode_by both of these two get two sets of longitude and latitude. This is what I'm trying, but it only geocodes_by the 'to' location and the from_lat and from_long columns are nil - probably just because the 'to' location is after the 'from' location.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  geocoded_by :from_address, :latitude => :from_lat, :longitude => :from_long
  geocoded_by :to_address, :latitude => :to_lat, :longitude => :to_long
  after_validation :geocode

  def from_address
    [fromstreet, fromcity, fromstate].compact.join(', ')
  end

  def to_address
    [tostreet, tocity, tostate].compact.join(', ')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this if anyone is curious:

Basically just added a new method called from_address_coords and called it before_save since geocoder gem will only save one set of coordinates - in this case, the from_address wasn't being saved.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  geocoded_by :to_address,   :latitude   => :to_lat,   :longitude => :to_long

  def to_address
    [tostreet, tocity, tostate].compact.join(', ')
  end

  def from_address
    [fromstreet, fromcity, fromstate].compact.join(', ')
  end

  def from_address_coords
    coords = Geocoder.coordinates(self.from_address)
    self.from_lat = coords[0]
    self.from_long = coords[1]
  end

  before_save :from_address_coords
  after_validation :geocode

end
```